# failure installing dell inspiron 1564 wireless driver

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

Opened up the back of the laptop, and there i saw a Broadcom bcm94312hmg wi-fi card.

Have tried the specific bcm94312hmg driver (which i hardly found), then tried every driver in Dell site, even the automatic scan, but none of them work. Shows that the setup didn't find the right hardware on my pc.

Don't know what else should i check or where to look? Could anyone help? A big thanks!

P.S. LAN is working fine. Could this be somehow the motherboard's fault or the wi-fi card's itself?

Comment: What specific model of Dell Laptop? Maybe the wifi card has failed, replace it with a new one of choice.

Comment: it's an inspiron 15 1564. My friend offered to check the wifi card's health with Kali linux, so i think i will try that.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thanks for the tip, it was the card's fault after all.

Answer (score 0):

The first indication of a potential fault with your Wi-Fi card may be changes to your network connection. In windows 8.1 and windows 10 it can manifest itself as the sporatic yellow exclamation on your network icon in the task bar. a problem with your Wi-Fi card could lead to network connections either becoming faulty or failing altogether.

Can you ping? 
Ping is a very useful tool to verify whether two devices have connectivity. It works by sending a ICMP echo request to a destination address, then measuring whether all, or any of those packets survived the trip and how long they took to get there and back. Disable the Ethernet adapter, first try to ping the default gateway of your network. It can be found in the command prompt using "ipconfig /all".(assuming windows says you are connected to a wifi network). Now you can use ping to test your Wi-Fi card for a response by opening up the Windows Command Prompt (or Terminal in Mac or linux), typing “ping 127.0.0.1”, and hitting Return. If the card does not respond, it may just be faulty or sometimes just needs to be reseated.

Your card  is not Visible in device manager?
Check for unrecognised devices, this would be an indication that the driver isn't installed for the card, or it has been corrupted.
Your Wi-Fi card should show up in Device Manager under the Network Adapters tab. If you do not see your card in the list, your computer will be unable to recognize that the card is there. Mac OSX users can use System Profiler.

If you are lucky!
If your Wi-Fi card or usb-adapter seems faulty, (drops out for no apparent reason untill you unplug replug or restart windows) you can attempt a fix by resetting it. (On-board cards) This can be done from the View Network Connections menu of the Windows Control Panel, by right clicking on the adapter's icon, clicking “disable”, then clicking “enable”. Look for updated drivers for your specific model WIFI card, alot of times this behavior can be fixed by the newest manufacturers drivers.

There is still hope!
In very rare cases there can be a corruption of registry keys that leaves 802.11 functionality broken. There are fixes for it by using the network connection troubleshooter, or the Microsoft ifixit tools. You can also try booting into another OS. An example would be a live boot Ubuntu, if this operating system also doesn't see the card, it's time to replace it!